# MongoDB Group and Push some values into an embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I have a Collection that has a schema like this one:

```
  _id   name   #week   KPI_1   KPI_2   KPI_3
  ...   AA001    01    0.93     0.35   0.88
  ...   AA001    49    0.97     0.40   0.98
  ...   AA001    50    0.96     0.30   0.98
```

And I would like to group that Collection into one like:

```
  _id   name        KPI_1           KPI_2           KPI_3
  ...   AA001   [ 01 : 0.93,      [ 01 : 0.35,   [01 : 0.88,
                  49 : 0.97,        49 : 0.40,    49 : 0.98
                  50 : 0.96         50 : 0.30     50 : 0.98
                ]                 ]              ]
```

But the problem is that my Collection has 70+ keys and I would like to push about 50 "columns", and I can't write one by one because the schema may change over time.

Is there anyway to select what "columns" NOT to push?

Answer (score 0):

You need use the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) aggregation pipeline stages for that.

Additional functions:

- [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) - converts an array into object.
- [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) - puts the generated object into array.

Example:

```
db.getCollection('t').aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            "KPI_1": { $push: { $arrayToObject: [[["$#week", "$KPI_1"]]] } },
            "KPI_2": { $push: { $arrayToObject: [[["$#week", "$KPI_2"]]] } },
            "KPI_3": { $push: { $arrayToObject: [[["$#week", "$KPI_3"]]] } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            "name": "$_id",
            "KPI_1": 1,
            "KPI_2": 1,
            "KPI_3": 1
        }
    }
])
```